# Playing with rowspan inside table

Tags: html, html-table

[image: Table distribution]

I'm trying to create the following distribution, but I have no idea how to organize number 3 and 4. I'm using rowspan for number 3. However number 4, It moves to second column because number 3 is taking the place.

How can I fix it?

---

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<!-- Table heading -->
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="center">1</th>
        <th class="center">2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<!-- // Table heading END -->

<!-- Table body -->
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">3</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">4</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
<!-- // Table body END -->
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you now have? Otherwise, all you will get is guesses. My guess is that not all table cells have content.

Comment: I have added code example

Comment: Add empty rows for `rowspan` to span

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is now. Cell 5 is moved to the left because there's nothing else there. Well, I'm afraid tables can't handle this. Use a grid instead. Anyway, you should mention you're using Bootstrap, since that doesn't seem clear.

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap, I created this classes by my own. Using bootstrap it's a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add empty rows for rowspan to have space

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border=1>
<!-- Table heading -->
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="center">1</th>
        <th class="center">2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<!-- // Table heading END -->

<!-- Table body -->
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">3</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">4</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
<!-- // Table body END -->
</table>
```

---

As you can see it's not very hard to arrange your items using table. It's better to use `<div>` grid system for that

```css
.row, .box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box.double {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box double">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box double">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should include Bootstrap. Then the OP's problem will be clear. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8weg0k85/1/).

Comment: @MrLister OP question is not using bootstrap (at least not mentioning that)

Comment: See the classes to their table. Also, if you include Bootstrap, the result looks like an attempt at making the table shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap, I created this classes by my own. Using bootstrap it's a solution?

Comment: @CarlesGrau Bootstrap is overkill if you need only grid system.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. As You are using rowspan so I added one more row as td value xyz. Please check.

Hope this can help you.

```css
tr th, tr td{
width:100px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid red;

}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<!-- Table heading -->
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="center">1</th>
        <th class="center">2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<!-- // Table heading END -->

<!-- Table body -->
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">3</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">4</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
<!-- // Table body END -->
</table>
```